# How to add keywords to tokenizer?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, token, tokenize

I am using generate_token function to tokenise a particular code . The problem is I am not able to add "print"  and "input" as keywords. It is returning them as NAME rather than keywords. How do I add these tokens ?

```
import token
import tokenize

try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO
file = open(filename)
characters = file.read()
file.close()
code_reader = StringIO(characters).readline

for num, (ttyp, ttok, _, _, _) in enumerate(tokenize.generate_tokens(code_reader)):
    print("%5d %15s %r" % (num, token.tok_name[ttyp], ttok))
```

Comment: PS: why are you reading the file into a string and then using StringIO to make it into a file-like thing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tokenize` module doesn't say anything about keywords.  All keywords are returned as NAME, then you have to decide which are keywords, usually by using the `keyword` module.  You can use some other means if you like, though.

Comment: when should we use keyword module? before the tokenize module ? to specify that I want "print" and "input" ? How to add this two words as keywords using keyword module.

Comment: Have you tried running your code?  You'll see that ttype is NAME for identifiers and keywords.  Then you can decide which are keywords however you like.

Comment: Ya I tried running my code and got the type as NAME. I saw the keyword module in the python doc and saw that we can only know wheather a particular word is keyword or not. there were no functions to add the words as keywords. Also the word "print" is python keyword still I am getting it as NAME in type.

Comment: @ThePresident: I've been trying to explain: tokenizer doesn't mark anything as a keyword.  All identifiers and keywords are returned as NAME.  You have to decide which are keywords, and which are not.  Most people do that by using the keyword module, but you can do it anyway you like.  You might want to check if the word is in the keyword module, or if the word is "input".  That would satisfy your criteria.